# Call Spring Boot Web app form angular and get responce

Tags: java, angular, spring, rest

I want to calling spring boot POST service from angular and rendering the JSP page on spring service. Now on jsp page on submit i need to send responce back to angualr.

//angular call

```
addOrder(order: Orders) {
return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/payment/add`, order);
}
```

//sping controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payment/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String Submit(@RequestParam("orderId") String orderId,@RequestParam("bankAccNo") String bankAccNo,@RequestParam("amount") Double amount,ModelMap model)
{
    logger.info("inside submit...");

    model.put("orderId", orderId);
    model.put("bankAccNo", bankAccNo);
    model.put("amount", amount);

    return "welcome";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/dopayment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody  String doPayment(@RequestParam("orderId") String orderId,@RequestParam("bankAccNo") String bankAccNo,@RequestParam("amount") Double amount,ModelMap model)
{

    String result = \\do processing for payment and it will return result.
    return result;
}
```

`
Above code will redirect to welcome.jsp. on that jsp page i have submit button

```
<form action="/dopayment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm">
<table align="center">
<div>
    <tr>
    <td>Order Id:</td>
    <td>${orderId}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Account No:</td>
    <td>${bankAccNo}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Amount:</td>
    <td>${amount}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><button name="submit" value="OK" type="submit">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <input type=hidden name=OrderId value=${orderId}>
    <input type=hidden name=bankAccNo value=${bankAccNo}>
    <input type=hidden name=amount value=${amount}>
    </div>
    </form>
```

when i click submit it will do /dopayment request on same controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dopayment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody  String doPayment(@RequestParam("orderId") String orderId,@RequestParam("bankAccNo") String bankAccNo,@RequestParam("amount") Double amount,ModelMap model)
{

    String result = \\do processing for payment and it will return result.
    return result;
}
```

I want to send this "result" variable to agian angualr request.

Can anyone help on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to do this I would say you are violating some design patterns and you should review your architecture..

Comment: @VictorCalatramas can you suggest how can i achieve this. This is basically a demo payment service running on spring boot. Request will come form angular.